# Grant permissions to run a SQL Server job

Tags: sql-server, permissions, sql-server-2005, jobs

I have a job on my SQL Server 2005 instance that I want to allow any database user to run.

I'm not worried about security, since the input to the job's actual work comes from a database table. Just running the job, without adding records to that table will do nothing.

I just can't find how to grant *public* permissions to the job.

Is there any way to do this?

The only thing I can think of at this point is to have the job constantly running (or on a schedule), but since it only needs to do any actual work rarely (maybe once every few months) and I do want the work to be done as soon as it exists, this does not seem to be an optimal solution.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could create a stored procedure that runs the job.  You can use `with execute as owner` to run the stored procedure as the database owner.  That way, the users themselves don't need permissons on `sp_start_job`.

```
create procedure dbo.DoYourJob
with execute as owner
as
exec sp_start_job @job_name = 'YourJob'
```

Grant execute rights on `DoYourJob` to allow people to start the job.

Of course, you can also put the contents of the job in a procedure, and grant rights to run that.  That would allow more interaction, like displaying a result text.

Comment: Still not working. I get the same error. I tried to create DoYourJob in the msdb database, as well as in my database, with the same results.

Comment: @shaharmo: Strange, I wonder who the database owner is?  You can also use `with execute as 'loginname'`, does that work?

Answer (score 5):

This will allow a specific user (user1) to run any SQL Agent job.

Members of `SQLAgentUserRole` and `SQLAgentReaderRole` can only start jobs that they own. Members of `SQLAgentOperatorRole` can start all local jobs including those that are owned by other users.

```
USE [msdb]
GO
CREATE USER [user1] FOR LOGIN [user1]
GO
USE [msdb]
GO
ALTER ROLE [SQLAgentOperatorRole] ADD MEMBER [user1]
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

The question says:

> I want to allow any database user to run

then

> I'm not worried about security

and also

> I just can't find how to grant public permissions to the job

Basically, permissions are needed on [`sp_start_job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms186757(v=sql.90)) (see permissions section).

The roles are described in "[SQL Server Agent Fixed Database Roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms188283(v=sql.90))" (linked from above)

Answer (score -1):

Jobs run from msdb schema and there is 'use msdb' forbidden in procedures. Hence, the procedure can be typed like this:

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[myJobToRun]
with execute as owner
as
exec [msdb].[dbo].[sp_start_job] @job_name = 'myJobToRunName'
```

Comment: How does your answer differ from the previously accepted answer?

Comment: Accepted comment lacks very important context part after exec: [msdb].[dbo]
Without it, you are unable to run this procedure from any other db than system one= MSDB.