# What should be the command for following role creation requirement?

Tags: sql-server-2012, permissions, users, role

I need to create a role where the assigned user can access only the 'AdventureWorksDB" where he will have execute permission to all tables,views and stored procedures in the database. I wrote the below script.

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
CREATE USER test1 FOR LOGIN test1;
GO 

CREATE ROLE db_executor

GRANT EXECUTE TO db_executor

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_executor', 'test1'
```

But he also needs `SQLAgentOperatorRole` permission for SQL Agent. But If I am to grant this I have to give him the access to `msdb` to be able to do this. But if I give the user , access to msdb user can access other databases as well. What could I do to make the user access only one database ad have full access to SQL Agent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure of any other alternative but i believe user needs to be there in MSDB or should have the admin rights to execute or perform any required action on the job. There is a connect item about this as well, [SQL2005 SQLAgent MSDB security roles](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/156852/sql2005-sqlagent-msdb-security-roles#tabs)

Or you can use an option as mentioned [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10449/grant-permissions-to-run-an-sql-server-job):

> You could create a stored procedure that runs the job. You can use
>   with `execute as owner` to run the stored procedure as the database
>   owner. That way, the users themselves don't need permissons on
>   sp_start_job

Also, if feasible, you can read [Launching SQL Agent Job from stored procedure not on [msdb] database, or, How Necessary is SET TRUSTWORTHY ON?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/98834/launching-sql-agent-job-from-stored-procedure-not-on-msdb-database-or-how-ne)